# How can I generate a webhook signal from Telegram notifications?

Tags: telegram

How can I generate a webhook signal from my Telegram notifications to another website automatically? Which software/service should i use? For example, I receive telegram notifications of types A, B and C from same source. When I receive only type of C notification, I want to transfer it to another platform with a webhook signal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle user notifications, you can use an MTProto library like [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) or [Pyrogram](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram).

If you just want to handle bot notifications, it will be easier to just use the [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).